# Webscrapping with Selenium

Tags: web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I use Jupyter Notebook on localhost and Google Chrome Driver
I'm trying to webscrap the following informations using Selenium.

[google page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmbkc.png)

I tried multiple things but always have an error message.

[Attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkS7Z.png)

[Attempt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCOeN.png)

[Attempt 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfZ0D.png)

[Attempt 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o6OT.png)

Sorry you'll have to copy paste to see the screenshot because the line of the links where detected as code line, dk why...

Can someone please help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to scrape? I can see you are using the wrong locators.

Comment: I'm trying to scrap the number 01

Comment: Try `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "your-class").text`